# Why can't I connect to Selenium Server?

Tags: r, rselenium

My RSelenuium script stopped working today, and I don't understand why. The code below is what I normally use to start my server.

```
library(RSelenium)

rd <- rsDriver(port = 4567L, browser = "chrome")
```

But now iÍ get the following error message:

Error in checkError(res) : 
  Couldnt connect to host on http://localhost:4567/wd/hub.
  Please ensure a Selenium server is running.
In addition: Warning message:
In rsDriver(port = 4567L, browser = "chrome") :
  Could not determine server status.

Then I try the following code:

```
selServ <- wdman::selenium(verbose = FALSE)
selServ$log()
```

and then I get the following error:

$stderr
[1] "Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile C:\Users\Allan\AppData\Local\binman\binman_seleniumserver\generic\3.6.0/selenium-server-standalone-3.6.0.jar"

$stdout
character(0)

So how do I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried re-downloading the jar and restarting the server?

Comment: @BryanOakley, thanks for your quick reply. I removed and reinstalled RSelenium package, and hoped that would re-download the jar. Is there any other way to re-download the jar?

Comment: Thank you once again @BryanOakley, That worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove versions using the `binman` package:

```
> binman::list_versions("seleniumserver")
$generic
 [1] "3.0.0"       "3.0.0-beta4" "3.0.1"       "3.1.0"       "3.2.0"      
 [6] "3.3.0"       "3.3.1"       "3.4.0"       "3.5.0"       "3.5.1"      
[11] "3.5.2"       "3.5.3"       "3.6.0"      

> binman::rm_version("seleniumserver", "generic", "3.6.0")
Removing version: 3.6.0 from platorm: generic
```

Running `rsDriver` will re-download the corrupted JAR:

```
> rD <- rsDriver()
checking Selenium Server versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
Creating directory: C:\Users\john\AppData\Local\binman\binman_seleniumserve...
Downloading binary: https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/seleni...

BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
checking chromedriver versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
checking geckodriver versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
checking phantomjs versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
[1] "Connecting to remote server"

# clean up
rm(rD)
gc()
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip @jdharrison, I'll use that next time.